# Let $F$ be a field. Show that if $p(x)$ is divided by $x-a$, the remainder is $p(a)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, field-theory

Could someone please verify whether I am missing something in my solution?

> Let $F$ be a field and $a\in F$. Show that if $p(x)\in F[x]$ is divided by $x-a$, the remainder is $p(a)$.

By the division algorithm, if $p(x)$ is divided by $x-a$, there exist unique polynomials $q(x),r(x)\in F[x]$ such that $p(x)=(x-a)q(x)+r(x)$ with $degr(x)<deg(x-a)=1$ or $r(x)=0$. Then $r(x)$ is a constant. If $x=a$, then $p(a)=(a-a)q(a)+r(a)$ or $p(a)=r(a)$. Then the remainder is $p(a)$.

> I feel I am missing something in my solution and not connecting ideas well.

Comment: This looks really good.  You have a couple of typos: $degr(x)$ should read $\text{deg}(r(x))$ and where you write $r(x) = 0$, you mean $\text{deg}(r(x))=0$.  You might want a sentence concluding that $r(x) = p(a)$.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time in looking through my solution! I think the $r(x)=0$ is correct though, I was copying from the division algorithm theorem in the textbook.

Comment: Think about what you are saying and how you are drawing the conclusion.  You want to say that $r(x)$ is a constant so you can go on to show that it is the particular constant $p(a)$.  You draw this conclusion because you know that $\text{deg}(r(x)) < \text{deg}(x-a)$ so $\text{deg}(r(x)) < 1$ so $\text{deg}(r(x)) = 0$.

Comment: Nothing wrong with this.  Many  basic proofs about fields are,   verbatim ,  the  proofs for the more familiar fields $\Bbb R$ and $ \Bbb Q,$ so it may help to ask, "Does this work if $F=\Bbb R$ or $F=\Bbb Q$?